# Error While sending a mail from Email subscription in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, smtpclient

I am getting below error while sending a mail from Email subscription in SSRS.

Below is the Configuration section:

```
<RSEmailDPConfiguration>
                        <SMTPServer>mysmtpserver addres</SMTPServer>
                        <SMTPServerPort>
                        </SMTPServerPort>
                        <SMTPAccountName>
                        </SMTPAccountName>
                        <SMTPConnectionTimeout>
                        </SMTPConnectionTimeout>
                        <SMTPServerPickupDirectory>
                        </SMTPServerPickupDirectory>
                        <SMTPUseSSL>
                        </SMTPUseSSL>
                        <SendUsing>2</SendUsing>
                        <SMTPAuthenticate>2
                        </SMTPAuthenticate>
                        <From>myid@domain.com</From>
                        <EmbeddedRenderFormats>
                            <RenderingExtension>MHTML</RenderingExtension>
                        </EmbeddedRenderFormats>
                        <PrivilegedUserRenderFormats>
                        </PrivilegedUserRenderFormats>
                        <ExcludedRenderFormats>
                            <RenderingExtension>HTMLOWC</RenderingExtension>
                            <RenderingExtension>NULL</RenderingExtension>
                            <RenderingExtension>RGDI</RenderingExtension>
                        </ExcludedRenderFormats>
                        <SendEmailToUserAlias>True</SendEmailToUserAlias>
                        <DefaultHostName>
                        </DefaultHostName>
                        <PermittedHosts>
                        </PermittedHosts>
                    </RSEmailDPConfiguration>
```

Error:

```
notification!WindowsService_0!1858!08/20/2013-05:48:02:: i INFO: Handling subscription f78a80f1-dd72-4215-b86a-96fa7391cfc0 to report ReportMenu, owner: mydomain\myid, delivery extension: Report Server Email.
library!WindowsService_0!1858!08/20/2013-05:48:02:: i INFO: RenderForNewSession('/ReportProject/ReportMenu')
library!WindowsService_0!1858!08/20/2013-05:48:04:: i INFO: Initializing EnableExecutionLogging to 'True'  as specified in Server system properties.
emailextension!WindowsService_0!1858!08/20/2013-05:48:04:: e ERROR: Error sending email. Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
   at System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String serverResponse)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.OnClose(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at System.Net.ClosableStream.Close()
   at System.Net.Mail.MailWriter.Close()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.EmailDeliveryProvider.EmailProvider.Deliver(Notification notification)
notification!WindowsService_0!1858!08/20/2013-05:48:04:: i INFO: Notification f06badda-98db-4aba-8a1f-26646430479b completed.  Success: True, Status: Failure sending mail: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender, DeliveryExtension: Report Server Email, Report: ReportMenu, Attempt 0
```

Could someone help on this ?

Comment: What user is the SSRS service running under? Is it `myid@domain.com`? Since you've already got authentication set up that seems like an error for whoever looks after your SMTP server.

Comment: How could I get the user under which SSRS service is running?  Not sure SMT server has any error. Because I tried to send mail from Powershell script, the mail was successfully sent.

Comment: The error is a permission issue direct from the SMTP server: `Mailbox unavailable` and `5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender`. I suspect there is a mismatch between the user authenticating to the SMTP server (i.e. the SSRS user) and the `<From>myid@domain.com</From>` value. You can see the SSRS service user in SQL Server Configuration Manager or just under the normal Services application `services.msc`.

Comment: The reporting server is running under NT Service\ReportServer. And I am using my id (domain\username) to send the mail. How should I proceed now?

Comment: Try running SSRS under your domain\username as a test. If that works I would recommend getting a domain user set up with a mailbox and run the SSRS service under that user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the exception, the issue is coming from the SMTP server:

> Status: Failure sending mail: Mailbox unavailable. The server response
>   was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

Because you have `SMTPAuthenticate` set to `2` in the config, the SSRS service user will try and authenticate to the SMTP server. See [Configure a Report Server for E-Mail Delivery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159155.aspx) for more details.

You need to resolve this issue - since SSRS is running under `NT Service\ReportServer` and trying to send the mail as `<From>myid@domain.com</From>` the SMTP server will not allow this, and hence the error.

As a test you can change the SSRS service user to `myid@domain.com` as a check to confirm this is the issue.

If so, you should investigate getting a domain user set up with a mailbox and running the SSRS service under that user.

Your other option is removing the Authentication option from the config (i.e. setting `SMTPAuthenticate` to `0`) and allowing anonymous authentication to the SMTP server, though this might not be allowed in your environment.

Comment: I have set SMTPAuthenticate to 2 and run SSRS as the user to the mail address I want to send and it still does not work. Error: 5.7.1 Unable to relay

Comment: If found your link helpful, [Configuring a Report Server for E-Mail Delivery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms159155(v=sql.105)), and also led me to another helpful page, [RSReportServer Configuration File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms157273%28v%3dsql.105%29).  And also this page, [MSDN Blogs: email subscriptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mariae/2013/01/04/configuring-reporting-services-to-send-email-subscriptions-outside-the-organization/).